# motoman MH50 with DX100 controller

Tags: ros, motoman-driver, motoman, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a Motoman MH50 robot with DX100 robot controller. I want to use it for pick and place application using Moveit!. In tutorial it is suggested that to order some part number to work with DX100 CONTROLLER:

What is use of this part number?

> The MotoROS application and source is available for public download. However, ordering this part number will ensure your controller is updated with correct system software, the MotoROS driver is installed, and all internal parameters are properly configured.

Or is it optional according to above line?

Is it sufficient if I only load MotoROS binary in controller?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/316165/motoman-mh50-with-dx100-controller/) by [nd](https://answers.ros.org/users/32578/nd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 80 on 2019-02-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> In tutorial it is suggested that to order some part number to work with DX100 CONTROLLER: [..] What is use of this part number?

It's not actually suggested, it's a requirement.

From [motoman_driver: Requirements](http://wiki.ros.org/motoman_driver#Requirements):

> However, for DX100 controllers, a specific software option must be explicitly ordered from Motoman in order to enable ROS-Industrial integration (see the [MotoPlus Runtime License](http://wiki.ros.org/motoman_driver#MotoPlus_Runtime_License) section below).

The *MotoPlus Runtime License* section then shows this:

[image: image description]

The license enables the controller to *run* a MotoPlus application, with MotoPlus being the SDK in which MotoROS is written.

> Is it sufficient if I only load MotoROS binary in controller?

No -- as I hope is clear now -- as that would not allow you to actually run it.

For that you'd need the license as well.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nd](https://answers.ros.org/users/32578/nd/) on 2019-02-20**:
Thanks for the clarification. it is not free right?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-20**:
Afaik: no, it's not free.

**Comment by [nd](https://answers.ros.org/users/32578/nd/) on 2019-02-20**:
thanks....